# Parenthesis in cronjob results in error

Tags: cron, shell

I am trying to run the following cronjob and I am getting the following error:

```
/bin/sh: -c: line 0: syntax error near unexpected token `)'
```

for the line:

```
mysqldump --opt -Q -h localhost --user=my_username --password=pass)word db_name | gzip -v9 - > db_backup.sql.gz
```

How do I properly run this cronjob to prevent issues with characters in the password?

Comment: What does the question have to do with ssh?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put the password in single quotes to avoid sh from processing the string. I.E.

```
--password='pass)word'
```

Comment: Or better yet, put it in a `.my.cnf` file in the appropriate user's home directory with appropriate ownership and permissions.